# Marking up a driver's license

Tags: driving

I'm not sure if this is the proper place for this question, but I want to know if coloring on a driver license invalidates it. I'm not talking about making real changes - more like coloring in sleeves or filling in a neckline.

Comment: Why would you expect that altering an official document will not invalidate it?

Comment: @Nij it's not a real alteration. A driver's license has a photo on it. I'm talking about making adjustments to the clothing in the photo

Comment: Yes, it’s a real alteration - you are changing the photograph the document issues approved to go on the document, that’s a real alteration.

Comment: @Moo I guess that's my answer:)

Comment: "It's not a real alteration" except that, it is an alteration and it is real...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a notary. If someone showed me a marked-up license, I'd refuse to perform the notarization, and make a note of the persons name and phone number, to make sure I would never make another appointment with the person.

Is there a law that says I have to refuse? I don't think so. Is there is a law that says I can refuse if I have any doubts about the person's identity? Absolutely.